# Linq to Sharepoint throws System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, linq

I have used entity class generated from SPMetal to retrieve data from sharepoint list. Frequently I am getting the below error on the sharepoint page and not able to do anything in the site. This error is occurring intermittently in the WebfrontServers. App pool recycle on the respective server resolve this issue(work around). Any insight/Suggesstions to resolve this issue would be greatly helpful.

Error:

```
An exception has occurred.   ExceptionType: 'IndexOutOfRangeException'
ExceptionMessage: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'   
StackTrace: '   
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()       
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.Util.<GetMappedFields>d__78.MoveNext()       
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__7a`1.MoveNext()       
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)       
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)       
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.SelectMappingInfo.GetDistinctMappedFields()       
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.Rules.PushDownProcessor.SelectWithInfoOp.PushDownSelect(Context ctx)       
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.Rules.PushDownProcessor.SelectWithInfoOp.Process(Context ctx)       
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq....        ...Rules.GuardedRule`4.<>c__DisplayClass7.<.ctor>b__6(TSourceBase src, TContext ctx)       
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.Rules.RewriteRule`2.Apply(TNode src, TContext ctx)       
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.Rules.CacheRule`3.Apply(TSource src, TContext ctx)       
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.Rules.PushDownProcessor.<.cctor>b__0(Expression e, Context ctx)       
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.Rules.ChildRule`2.Apply(TNode src, TContext ctx)       
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.Rules.PushDownProcessor.<.cctor>b__3(Expression e, Context ctx)       
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.Rules.RewriteRule`2.Apply(TNode src, TContext ctx)       
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.Rules.CacheRule`3.Apply(TSource src, TContext ctx)       
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.SPLinqProvider.Rewrite(Expression expression, List`1& assumptions)     6d7b9dc9-cade-4158-a7fd-69c7d81ac670              
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.SPLinqProvider.RewriteAndCompile[T](Expression expression, List`1& assumptions)       
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.LinqQuery`1.GetEnumerator()       
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()       
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)       
at Customwebpart.SetTabs(IEnumerable`1 getTabList)       
at Customwebpart.TabControlPresenter.OnViewInitialized()'   
Source: 'Customwebpartcontrols - ID=c67056e2-31ce-4032-89f0-7d34f65dd5f4'   
TargetSite: 'Boolean MoveNext()'    6d7b9dc9-cade-4158-a7fd-69c7d81ac670
```